# A better tag name for soft-questions?

Tags: discussion, tags

We have a rather clear idea about what we call a soft-question, but it seems that the name is not as expressive as we would like it to be, in particular a new user or a person just visiting the site might not understand what we mean by a soft-question. AFAIR, we didn't choose the name, we just inherited it from the practice on MO.

What do you think about replacing it with a more expressive name?

Do you have any suggestions for what would be a better name?

Comment: I think it's fine the way it is.

Comment: this is also why we have those little description boxes for tags.

Comment: @ArtemKaznatcheev refers to the tag wiki, this should be good and clear and succinct for all common tags (for example, all tags on this page: http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/tags) -- any assistance in creating good tag wiki excerpts is always welcome!

Answer (score 4):

I haven't heard complaints about it. I think this falls into the "if it ain't broke..." category.

Comment: At least Kaveh expressed his dissatisfaction about the name, and so did I.  Although we cannot make everything perfect, we can try to fix some of the minor glitches.

Answer (score 1):

I agree that the meaning of the tag [soft-question](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/soft-question) is unclear from the tag name.  However, the problem is that it seems difficult to come up with a more descriptive name which is concise enough to look reasonable.  Personally I prefer to call it [not-in-tcs-but-about-tcs](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/not-in-tcs-but-about-tcs) (24 characters), but I can imagine that most people would not like it.  If there is a good name, I may agree with renaming.

Comment: "TCS culture"...

Comment: @Aaron: That sounds better.

Comment: Looking at the top questions in this tag, it seems clear that not all of them are cultural. Some are cultural but it seems more of them ("How to shoot down your proofs" and "How do I referee a paper?") are "how to do TCS". Perhaps "TCS-howto"?